# How to get id of first element (form) in body using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not much familiar with JQuery; I want to get id of form element in jquery which is located in following location

```
<body>
   <div id="boxDialog"> </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
       Many Tables and divs
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="approval"></form> 

 Jquery: : : 
alert($("body.form").attr("id"));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j32f9128/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

`body.form` will select the `body` element having class of `form`, which doesn't exists so returns `undefined`.

**Solution:**

Use space between the `body` and `form` and remove `.`. Using space, the `form` element will be searched in `body`.

```
alert($("body form").attr("id"));
```

You can also ommit `body` here as all the `forms` are nested inside `body`.

```
alert($("form").attr("id"));
```

If you want to get the `id` of **first** form element, you can use `first()`.

```
alert($("form").first().attr("id"));
```

Or you can also

```
alert($("form:first").attr("id"));
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j32f9128/1/)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation including my mistake too.

Comment: Is this also fine -> $("body > form").attr("id") ?

Comment: @fatherazrael This is `child` selector, this will select only **direct** descendents of the `body`

Comment: @fatherazrael If your `form` element is directly placed in `body` you can also use `>` selector

Comment: Directly means? aren't above all examples quoted by you are for direct descendants? and how > is different from selecting using Space?

Comment: @fatherazrael `<body><form>...</body` this is directly, so you can use `>`. `<body><div><form>....`, this is not so you cannot use `>`. Using space will find any grand child descendents

Answer (score 1):

You have used `form` as classname. your selector tries to find element body that has class `form`

You should rather use space that indicate matching against descendants or find selector along with tagname selectors for both body and form:

```
$("body form").attr("id");
```

which is equivalent to

```
$("body").find("form").attr("id");
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cLv2sj8k/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`$('form').attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

> How to get id of first element (form) in body using JQuery?

This will get you the first form element's id in  the body

```
$('body').find('form').eq(0).attr('id');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j32f9128/2/)